# Cannot use '@try' with Objective-C exceptions disabled

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, exception, try-catch

Im trying to make a category in Obj-C and use `@try-catch` because there is no other way to check if an identifier in a `UIStoryboard` exists.

```
- (UIViewController *)viewControllerWithID:(NSString *)key {
    UIViewController *vc;

    @try { // ERROR: Cannot use '@try' with Objective-C exceptions disabled
        vc = [self instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:key];
    }
    @catch (NSException *ex) {}

    return vc;
}
```

> Cannot use '@try' with Objective-C exceptions disabled

I googled that error and found that I have to check if `Enable Objective-C Exceptions` was set to yes in build settings. I checked and it is set to yes.

Its the only solution I have found and it isnt working.

Im using XCode 6.2 and this is a Swift project but Swift doesnt support @try-catch so thats why I do this in Obj-C.

---

When I set the same setting to no I get a duplicate error message and when I set it to yes again i only get one error message. This is really weird.

Comment: Did you try cleaning (Cmd-Shift-K) then trying to build again? Sometimes Xcode doesn't "forget" about errors even if they're fixed until the project is cleaned.

Comment: But I didnt change anything

Comment: This must be a bug in xcode 6.2

Comment: Can you explain why you need this category? Under what circumstance would you not know if you had a controller with a particular identifier?

Comment: @rdelmar URL schemes etc.

Comment: Let's all calm down. The OP's question is valid and interesting for its own sake. Suggesting other ways to accomplish the same ultimate ends is also valid.

Comment: @matt I suggested an alternative and the OP decided to down vote it.

Comment: I reiterate:  it is a general point in Cocoa that it is dangerous to try to use exceptions for program control.  If you catch an exception that has been propagated through code you can't inspect, you cannot guarantee that the stack has been unwound correctly, releasing all the resources.  This exception is a symptom of a programming error.  It should not be caught.

Answer (score 1):

You simply shouldn't even be trying to catch this exception.  If you try to instantiate a view controller that doesn't exist it's a serious programming error.   Surely you know when you write the code what view controllers there are?

**Edit**

Let me expand a bit.  If you want to choose a view controller based on (say) user input, you should validate that it is in a list of allowable view controllers (that you write) **before** you try to instantiate it, so you don't ever see the exception.

Comment: But I dont want to do it like that. I want to be able to do if let vc = sb. instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(key) {}

Comment: Which I cannot do because apple doesnt support that.

Comment: @Arbitur No, you write the code to do that.  You include in your code an list of all the allowable view controller identifiers and you check if the one you are about to use is in the list.

Comment: And what is the error in doing the way I want it? I just want a 100% failsafe solution with minimum effort and my way is the most elegant imo.

Comment: @Arbitur Your way is not elegant at all, it's wrong.  You must know when you write the code which identifiers are valid - after all you assign the identifier to each view controller.  Why can't you make an array of the identifiers and just test to see if key is in it?

Comment: What if I have a very big project with many viewcontrollers? I dont find writing a large list with copypasting into an array and then search for it in there. My solution is working perfectly in action after I changed to xcode6.3

Comment: @Arbitur Your solution only works because of dumb luck.  In fact it may be leaking objects - have you tried instrumenting it?  You can carry on using it if you like, but this is not an approach that should be recommended to anybody else.

Comment: Hm I just checked for ram usage in xcode Debug session but Ill check in instruments aswell and return.

Comment: I tested for leaks in instruments and no leaks were found

Comment: I apologize for my angry attitude yesterday, it was not ok of me to release my frustration on you and Im really sorry.

Comment: That's OK, I went in a bit hard myself :)

Answer (score 0):

As I thought it was a stupid bug in XCode 6.2 when I transfered my files to XCode 6.3 it didnt give me the error anymore.

Comment: You should not be using exceptions in this way.